# Bash script with while loop that waits for a file to be refreshed but kills if time threshold is exceeded

Tags: bash, kill, sleep

I am very basic with bash so apologies if this is obvious to solve and please let me know if more details are needed. The script below is part of a larger script to launch a python workflow and wait for the results.json file to be updated at the end of the workflow.

I have tried to use

```
{
    sleep 1m
    kill $$
}&
```

but this generates the error when the results.json file does get refreshed within the 1 minute:

*kill: (90015) - No such process*

This is the script:

```
#! /bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0

export outputfile=results.json

if [[ ! -e $outputfile ]]; then
    touch $outputfile
fi

OldTimestamp=$(date -r $outputfile)

{
    sleep 1m
    kill $$
}&

NewTimestamp=$OldTimestamp; 
while [ "$NewTimestamp" = "$OldTimestamp" ]; do 
   sleep 0.1
   NewTimestamp="$(date -r $outputfile)" 
done
```

Comment: Can't you do it sequentially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is get rid of that *kill: (90015) - No such process* error, you could check to see if the process is still running before killing it:

```
{
    sleep 1m
    ps -p $$ > /dev/null && kill $$
}&
```

But I would actually not use kill at all. You can just keep track of how many times you've interated over the while loop, and break the loop after a suitable number of iterations:

```
NewTimestamp=$OldTimestamp; 
iterations=0
while [ "$NewTimestamp" = "$OldTimestamp" ] && [ $iterations -lt 600 ]; do
   sleep 0.1
   NewTimestamp="$(date -r $outputfile)"
   let iterations++
done
```

If you want to exit with a non-zero exit code if the file wasn't updated, you could add afterwards:

```
if [ "$NewTimestamp" = "$OldTimestamp" ] ; then 
    echo "results.json was not updated" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Or similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I have implemented this and works well. Only very minor note are the "" missing in
`if [ "$NewTimestamp" = "$OldTimestamp" ]`

Comment: Yep, I'll fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it in this way, this is why you're getting that error when your results.json has successfully been produced: When you put the sleep and kill in the braces, that's call a group command. When you put the ampersand after the braces, that puts it into the background in a sub-shell (the `$$` still works because it was changed to the current pid on parsing and execution of the group command). If your Python program finishes successfully, nothing has told that subprocess running the sleep & kill to go away. When the sleep expires, it runs the kill, and because your original script is no longer running, it complains about "no such process".

Here's how you can make it work. Run `kill %1` after you have your successful result, and that will kill off the sleep & kill.

```bsh
OldTimestamp=$(date -r $outputfile)

{
    sleep 1m
    kill $$
}&

NewTimestamp=$OldTimestamp; 
while [ "$NewTimestamp" = "$OldTimestamp" ]; do 
   sleep 0.1
   NewTimestamp="$(date -r $outputfile)" 
done

echo "I have found my $outputfile and am done"
kill %1   # Kill off the subprocess which would have killed off this script
```

---

I said above "if you must..." because this isn't the typical way that one would write this. Normally you would use a `timeout` command to run the Python script which is supposed to create your results.json. That way, you can check the status of that run, and if unsuccessful, simply quit the script.

It also has the benefit of killing off the report generator after your timeout duration is reached. The method above does not: if the report generator is just running slow, you'll see it still running in the background even though the top-level script has finished. (I'm making some assumptions about how your system works, but in general this method will only stop the top-level script and not anything the script has started itself)

If your python script is called "makereport.py", we could do something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export outputfile=results.json
OldTimestamp=$(date +"%s" -r $outputfile)  # Use %s so we have a simple integer

timeout 1m makereport.py
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "makereport.py failed"
    exit 1
fi

# At this point you can either assume report.json was created, or you
# can check it like you did before
CurTimestamp=$(date +"%s" $outputfile)
if [[ $CurTimestamp = $OldTimestamp ]]; then
    echo "makereport.py finished successfully, but a new report was not generated"
fi
echo "Verified we have a new report.json ready to go"
```

Comment: Thanks, the script can indeed become very slow, but this answer works as well as that of frabjous that I have marked as correct only as submitted earlier. I appreciate the explanation - I am new so I can't give an upvote to this, but it would be well deserved.